# Syntax for the customized methods when extending Liferay MVCPortet

Tags: liferay, portlet, liferay-6

I am using Liferay 6 for development.

I have one query with respect to extending `MVCPortlet` class and providing the methods.

In some of the examples, during extending `MVCPortlet` and providing customized methods, is it mandatory to provide the parameters as `ActionRequest` and `ActionResponse` to the method as shown below:

```
public void addBook(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response) {

}
```

So my question is, is this syntax mandatory?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's mandatory as this implements an action handler. You can also override GenericPortlet's processAction with the same parameters or use the @ProcessAction annotation, but in all cases you'll have to have a way to pass the actual request into the portlet. And that's what the parameters are for.

If you don't provide the parameters, the method will not be found by MVCPortlet's reflection-based resolving of the actual action name.